# Работа с изображением в методе cvtColor opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

я бы  хотел уточнить что делает этот метод с такими параметрами:

```
    cv::cvtColor(input, input, COLOR_BGRA2RGB);
    cv::cvtColor(input, input, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

На сколько я понял, первый удаляет альфа канал, а второй сужает пиксель в байт, но в этом не уверен.
Теперь хочу узнать два момента, правильно ли я понял , и какое действе с пикселями происходит в этих двух методах ?

Comment: Первая функция не только удаляет альфаканал, но и меняет порядок следования цветов с bgr на rgb. Вторая функция переводит изображение в однотоновое (черно-белое). Правда второй вызов неверный, так как порядок следования цветов в изображении обратный

Comment: Благодарю, а можно немного подробнее, как он это делает на уровне байтов - пикселей. Он просто обнуляет альфа - байт?

Comment: И как мне узнать порядок расположение цветов по байтам?

Comment: 1) не он не обнуляет альфу, а просто копирует в новую матрицу все значения кроме нее (ну и еще переставляет их). 2) никак - вы должны знать это изначально.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Первая функция не только удаляет альфаканал, но и меняет порядок следования цветов с bgr на rgb. Вторая функция переводит изображение в однотоновое (черно-белое). Правда второй вызов неверный, так как порядок следования цветов в изображении обратный.